# Chrome headless can't access URL on network in docker-compose

Tags: google-chrome, docker, docker-compose, google-chrome-headless

The quick description of the problem is:

- I have docker-compose setup with 2 services: `app` and `test`
- I can get chrome headless within `test` to reach public URLs
- I can get `test` to successfully curl to `app`
- But I *can't* get `test` to load URLs that on the docker-compose network in chrome headless

I have a docker-compose file with two services like so:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: App.Dockerfile
      ports:
        - 5000:5000
      restart: always
  test:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Chrome.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - app
```

The `Chrome.Dockerfile` installs chrome like so:

```
FROM node:8-slim

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /src/*.deb

ADD entrypoint .
CMD ./entrypoint
```

And the entrypoint script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ""
echo "Demonstrates that curl can access the host app on port 5000..."
echo ""
curl http://app:5000/

echo ""
echo "Demonstrates that chrome headless is working..."
echo ""

google-chrome \
--headless  \
--disable-gpu  \
--no-sandbox  \
--dump-dom \
http://example.com/

echo ""
echo "Demonstrates that chrome headless is not successful with app:500"
echo

google-chrome \
--headless  \
--disable-gpu  \
--no-sandbox  \
--dump-dom \
--enable-logging --v=10000 \
http://app:5000/
```

The output looks like this:

```
Starting experiment_app_1 ... done

Demonstrates that curl can access the host app on port 5000...

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>A page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>A heading</h1>
  </body>
</html>

Demonstrates that chrome headless is working...

[0303/074652.347092:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
libudev: udev_has_devtmpfs: name_to_handle_at on /dev: Operation not permitted
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 146: blank doesn't take any effect anymore. please remove it from your fonts.conf
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  ...all the html from example.com
</html>

Demonstrates that chrome headless is not successful with app:5000

[0303/074652.598662:VERBOSE1:zygote_main_linux.cc(336)] ZygoteMain: initializing 0 fork delegates
[0303/074652.599327:INFO:cpu_info.cc(50)] Available number of cores: 4
[0303/074652.603129:ERROR:gpu_process_transport_factory.cc(1007)] Lost UI shared context.
[0303/074652.603580:VERBOSE1:pulse_stubs.cc(683)] dlopen(libpulse.so.0) failed, dlerror() says:
libpulse.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[0303/074652.603681:VERBOSE1:pulse_util.cc(106)] Failed on loading the Pulse library and symbols
[0303/074652.603843:VERBOSE1:webrtc_internals.cc(114)] Could not get the download directory.
libudev: udev_has_devtmpfs: name_to_handle_at on /dev: Operation not permitted
[0303/074652.609098:VERBOSE1:breakpad_linux.cc(1997)] Non Browser crash dumping enabled for: renderer
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 146: blank doesn't take any effect anymore. please remove it from your fonts.conf
[0303/074652.708611:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)] Adding CT log: Google 'Aviator' log
...more logs
[0303/074652.708843:VERBOSE1:multi_log_ct_verifier.cc(75)] Adding CT log: Certly.IO log
[0303/074652.708853:VERBOSE1:proxy_service.cc(955)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
[0303/074652.713231:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(30)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: http://app:5000/
[0303/074652.715447:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(30)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https://app:5000/
[0303/074652.719183:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(1098)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[0303/074652.738050:VERBOSE2:ThreadState.cpp(533)] [state:0x55a5e7840fc0] ScheduleGCIfNeeded
...
[0303/074652.742949:VERBOSE1:V8ContextSnapshot.cpp(140)] A context is created from snapshot for main world
[0303/074652.746847:VERBOSE2:ThreadState.cpp(496)] [state:0x55a5e7840fc0] SchedulePageNavigationGCIfNeeded: estimatedRemovalRatio=0.75
[0303/074652.749427:VERBOSE1:V8ContextSnapshot.cpp(140)] A context is created from snapshot for main world
[0303/074652.763112:VERBOSE1:sandbox_ipc_linux.cc(131)] SandboxIPCHandler stopping.
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

So if curl works, and chrome headless works, why can't chrome headless load the `http://app:5000` URL?

Here's a complete repo that shows the problem: https://github.com/zilkey/docker-compose-chrome-headless-error

NOTE 1: The `libudev: udev_has_devtmpfs: name_to_handle_at on /dev: Operation not permitted` could be related, and I can solve that a few ways such as cap add sys_admin but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

NOTE 2: Regarding the `ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl`, the app doesn't expose SSL, so this is to be expected (I think).

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly *why* yet, but changing the service name from `app` to something other than `app` fixes it:

`version: '3'
services:
  other:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: App.Dockerfile
      ports:
        - 5000:5000
      restart: always
  test:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Chrome.Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - other`

Apparently Chrome (at least the way I set it up) handles `http://app:5000/` differently from `http://other:5000`.